# Зачем нужны абстрактные классы?

Tags: php, ооп

Какую роль в этом коде (из книги) играют абстрактные классы?

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php 

trait GetSumLine {
function CalculTax($price){
return ( ( $this->expirience() ) * $price );
}
abstract function expirience();
}

abstract class Service{
//Сервис 
 }

class Object{
use GetSumLine {
    GetSumLine::CalculTax as private;
}

function __construct($price){
$this->price = $price;
}

public function expirience(){
return 20;
}

public function GetEndSum(){
    return ($this->CalculTax($this->price));
}
}



$doc = new Object(320);
 print "{$doc->GetEndSum()}";
```

Comment: вчера писал Вам ответ на этот же вопрос, но злобные модераторы удалили его раньше ))

Comment: Наверно не заметил (не успел) , но и тебе спасибо)

Comment: я не успел отправить) удалили раньше

Comment: если по теме то просто почитайте про ооп, не обязательно в разрезе пхп, вероятно книга из которой вы привели пример не огонь

Comment: я бы не сказал что она не огонь , все таки целенаправленна на ООП . Книга "php объекты шаблоны и методики программирования" от Мэтт Зандстра , если интересно

Comment: просто тогда странно что у Вас возник вопрос про абстрактные классы, это одна из основ ооп... инкапсуляция, полиморфизм, наследование

Comment: вопросов с абстрактными классами нет , просто не понятна была их польза

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве примера:

Классы `Bear` и `Monkey` наследуются от абстрактного класса `Animal`, в игре про зоопарк, для того чтобы узнать можно или нельзя кормить животное экземплярами классов `Banana` и `Honey`, которые наследуют класс `Food`, у `Animal` вы добавляете метод без реализации `canEat(Food)` а в классах-наследниках уже реализуете его в соответствии с их логикой.

Польза здесь вот в чем: теперь во всех местах где вы захотите узнать можно ли накормить животное едой вы будете оперировать классами еда и животное, при этом, когда вы захотите добавить в игру свинью и трюфели вам не придется менять уже написанный код, который оперирует животными и едой.

Это касается как интерфейсов так и абстрактных классов, можно считать что интерфейс это вырожденый случай абстрактного класса.

Answer (score 2):

Основная цель абстрактных классов - практическая реализация полиморфизма, то есть базовое описания методов, которые должны быть переопределены в классах потомках.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь хоть представление имею о них